# AWS CodeBuild: Building application with elasticsearch unit tests fails to run as root

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-codebuild

We are building our application on CodeBuild and have unit tests that spawn a elastic daemon to run some tests. However, the unit tests fails with the exception that elasticsearch can't run as root but CodeBuild always run commands as root.

Are there any recommended workarounds? 
Is there any command in elastic 6+ to run as root?

Thanks

Error:
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script needs to run as a specific user, you may use the "run-as" option as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped. The docs are not entirely clear but you basically need to create your own custom docker image that has that user already created and then in your buildspec file you can leverage the "run-as" command.